# Django; Bugsnag doesn't work with Gunicorn with Eventlet

Tags: django, gunicorn, eventlet, bugsnag

Testing `BugSnag` with our `Django` based REST-API server. I have an API endpoint that crashes on purpose just to test it, someone in a certain serializer my views use.

In my own `settings.py` I have:

```
BUGSNAG = {
    'api_key': '[redacted]',
    'app_version': "1.0",
    'project_root': "/path/to/my/project/folder/where/manage.py/is",
    'release_stage': "development",
    'notify_release_stages': ['development', 'staging', 'production']
}


MIDDLEWARE = (
    'bugsnag.django.middleware.BugsnagMiddleware',
    <all other middleware>
)
```

When I run my server like this: `gunicorn myproj.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload` or `python manage.py runserver` `BugSnag` reports all crashes correctly.

**However**, when I use `gunicorn myproj.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload --worker-class eventlet` BugSnag stops sending bug reports when exception occurr. The only clue I have for this behavior is this:

`2020-02-08 02:34:37,363 - [bugsnag] ERROR - Notifying Bugsnag failed wrap_socket() got an unexpected keyword argument '_context'`

Why does BugSnag stop working when `gunicorn` is used with the `eventlet` worker class? I am completely at a loss here. There is zero references to the subject online as if this problem only occurs on my computer.... not very encouraging.

Comment: This is why: https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/526

Comment: Yep. thanks. Rolling back to Python 3.6.5 resolved it. If you write your comment as an answer I can accept it to credit you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolled back to Python 3.6.5 to make it work -- Eventlet has an SSL issue with Python 3.7 still unfixed. It's virtually unusable on 3.7